# Работа с COM портом в C#

Tags: c#, serialport

Проблема заключается в том что экземпляр SerialPort работает не в потоке UI. Поэтому пришлось сделать вот так чтобы писать принятые данные в текстовое поле.

```
        private void comPort_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
        {
            while (comPort.BytesToRead > 0)
                ReceivedText.Invoke(new Action(() => ReceivedText.Text += Convert.ToChar(comPort.ReadChar())));
            
         }
```

А уже обрабатываю принятые сообщения по событию изменения свойства Text объекта TextField.
Такой вариант работает, но проблема в том что когда происходит необрабатываемое исключение то отладчик всегда останавливается на строчке с invoke и непонятно где именно произошла ошибка.
Вопрос: можно ли как-нибудь организовать вызов метода-обработчика сообщений чтобы этот недостаток устранить?

Comment: Сначала считайте весь текст из порта, а уже потом пишите его в текстбокс.

Comment: `А уже обрабатываю принятые сообщения по событию изменения свойства Text объекта TextField` в корне неверный подход. Обрабатывайте когда считали из порта, а не когда обновляется UI.